# Updating Git Submodule Fails

Tags: git, ssh, github, git-submodules

I am trying to clone a git repo that contains submodules onto a Namecheap shared server using SSH. The 'git clone' command worked fine, except that one of my submodules failed. When I try to run 'git submodule update' it fails as well. I get the error;

```
github.com[0: 207.97.227.239]: errno=Connection timed out
fatal: unable to connect a socket (Connection timed out)
Clone of 'git://github.com/WordPress/Wordpress.git' into submodule path 'wordpress' failed
```

I tried contacting Namecheap to see if there was a Firewall or something blocking the connection. They said there is no firewall that would be blocking this. Also, all of my other submodules on GitHub updated fine. Regardless, I tried using the https protocol instead and still had no luck.

Any ideas what is going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, a "`errno=Connection timed out`" should indicate an issue on the GitHub side (their [status report page](https://status.github.com/) indicates they had a few issue on the 21st and 20th of September)

So unless the issue still persists (in which case, the root cause might be on your side), GitHub should have resolved it by now.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the status page!

Answer (score 3):

You could specify to use https:// instead of git:// for GitHub with the following command:

```
git config --global url."https://github".insteadOf git://github
```

Comment: This solution worked perfectly for a project with submodules and sub sub modules that were configured for git:// protocol from behind a corporate proxy.  Simply run the command above, then do "git submodule update --init --recursive"